# PostgreSQL sort consecutive records by clusters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to sort some records consecutively by a numeric value. I need use the `lead()` and `lag()` functions but I don't have idea how.

****The Table ****

```
lote        cod_guia    box     des_prod 
1,50731E+14   42012    50434    MERLUZA DEL SUR ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO
1,51E+14    42012   50435   MERLUZA DEL SUR ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO
1,51E+14    42012   50436   MERLUZA DEL SUR ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO
```

my sql

```
Select 
    packing_acum.lote as lote_completo,
    m_pesaje.cod_guia,
    --lag(packing_acum.corr,1) over wt as anterior,
    min(packing_acum.corr),
    max(packing_acum.corr),
    --lead(packing_acum.corr,1) over wt as proximo,
    producto.des_prod ,
   case when packing.tipo = 1 THEN 'ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO' ELSE 'CONGELADO' end  as estado_fresco_o_congelado 
From m_pesaje 
 inner join ( producto 
 inner join (packing 
 inner join packing_acum 
    on packing.cod_packing = packing_acum.cod_packing) 
    on packing_acum.cod_prod = producto.cod_prod) 
    on packing_acum.cod_pesaje = m_pesaje.cod_pesaje 
where 
    packing_acum.estado = 5668 and packing_acum.cod_prod <> 0
group by lote_completo,cod_guia,des_prod,estado_fresco_o_congelado
order by 
    min(packing_acum.corr),max(packing_acum.corr)
```

**result:**

```
lote    cod_guia    box_ini box_end des_prod        estado_fresco_o_congelado
1,50731E+14 42012   50434   50507   MERLUZA DEL SUR ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO
1,50731E+14 41934   50498   50502   MERLUZA DEL SUR ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO
1,50731E+14 42010   50503   50505   MERLUZA DEL SUR ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO
```

**I need:**

```
lote    cod_guia    box_ini box_end des_prod        estado_fresco_o_congelado
1,50731E+14 42012   50434   50497   MERLUZA DEL SUR ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO
1,50731E+14 41934   50498   50502   MERLUZA DEL SUR ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO
1,50731E+14 42010   50503   50505   MERLUZA DEL SUR ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO
1,50731E+14 42012   50505   50507   MERLUZA DEL SUR ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO
```

Comment: Please give more context, its unclear what your SQL is supposed to do nor why the result you need has more records than the result you're getting

Comment: thank you... look the result table and look the table result that i want... i need separate the number for consecutive values... min_value(box-ini) -> max_value(box-End)

Comment: I still don't really understand. You'll need to show the *input* too, i.e. the table(s) and data involved.

Comment: thx.. below the table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have to group on consecutive "paired" rows (consecutive by `packing_acum.corr`, paired by `m_pesaje.cod_guia`), or so it seems from the data you supply. You can not do this with the `lag()` and `lead()` window functions because you have nothing to suitably `PARTITION` on. Instead, you should first create some value to `GROUP` on, then you can use simple aggregate functions.

Seeing that you do not provide table definitions, sample data or PostgreSQL version, the below is somewhat guesswork but it might just work for you.

```
SELECT sub.lote_completo, sub.cod_guia, sub.box_ini, sub.box_end, 
       producto.des_prod,
       CASE WHEN packing.tipo = 1 THEN 'ENFRIADO REFRIGERADO' ELSE 'CONGELADO'
       END AS estado_fresco_o_congelado
FROM (  

  SELECT lote AS lote_completo, cod_guia, cod_packing, cod_prod,
         min(corr) AS box_ini, max(corr) AS box_end
  FROM (

    SELECT pa.lote, pes.cod_guia, pa.corr, pa.cod_packing, pa.cod_prod,
           row_number() OVER (ORDER BY pa.corr) -
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pes.cod_guia ORDER BY pa.corr) AS cls
    FROM packing_acum pa
    JOIN m_pesaje pes USING (cod_pesaje)
    WHERE pa.estado = 5668
      AND pa.cod_prod <> 0) subsub

  GROUP BY lote, cod_guia, cod_packing, cod_prod, cls) sub

JOIN producto USING (cod_prod)
JOIN packing USING (cod_packing)
ORDER BY sub.box_ini, sub.box_end;
```

In the `subsub` sub-query the pseudo-class number `cls` is generated by subtracting the row number over the entire table (after filtering on the two conditions in the `WHERE` clause) by the row number in the partition over the `cod_guia` value. This gives numbers starting from 0, but having no special value or property other than that "boxes" (`pa.corr`) in adjacent rows with the same value for `cod_guia` have the same `cls` value.

In the `sub` sub-query you aggregate on that `cls` value, generating the minimum and maximum box numbers and in the main query you add the other required columns.

Comment: thx a lot.. this query is awesome. but i have a problem.. 1.- the sub and subsub qry work.. but when I run the entire query gives an error in join

Comment: thx a lot.. this query is awesome. but i have a problem.. <br/> when I run the entire query gives an error in join <br/> say Error: "cod_prod" column specified in the USING clause does not exist in the left table
SQL state: 42703, thx again.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Both `cod_prod` and `cod_packing` are in the `subsub` sub-query, but they should also be in the `sub` sub-query select list and `GROUP BY` clause. See updated answer.